# creating custom UI component button inside textView with borders

Tags: android, button, coding-style, custom-controls

I created a custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="#5a803f"
                android:endColor="#446c1a" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#3d5e1d" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp"
                android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="#5a803f"
                android:endColor="#446c1a" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#3d5e1d" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp"
                android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>

    </item>

</selector>
```

But I need to place this button to the black background with defined margins and with white borders at the top and bottom. And this background shouldn't be clickable. Something like this:

[image]

How can I implement this? with the help of this selector or style using. Help please with a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using the TableLayout. In this case my TextView is looks like:

```
   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    style="@style/button_row"
    >
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
        style="@style/custom_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Log In"
         />
    </TableRow>
```

etc for all UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Button  Layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Button android:id="@+id/textAndIconBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text in the button"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
```

For more information you can try [this Link](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/)